# Javascript Map Data that matches variable value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, char

I have been working on a **Chart project** and I need to show some value using tooltip when I move the mouse over the chart area. So this is my data that I need to map-

```
    {  
   "item":[  
      {  
         "name":"abcd",
         "in":12,
         "out":2,
         "net":10,
         "child":[  
            {  
               "name":"Test",
               "in":2,
               "out":2,
               "net":0,
               "child":null
            },
            {  
               "name":"Max",
               "in":10,
               "out":0,
               "net":10,
               "child":null
            }
         ]
      },
      {  
         "name":"Dress",
         "in":43,
         "out":0,
         "net":43,
         "child":[  
            {  
               "name":"Class-1",
               "in":35,
               "out":0,
               "net":35,
               "child":null
            },
            {  
               "name":"One",
               "in":8,
               "out":0,
               "net":8,
               "child":null
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

I need to map `child` when it matches with any of the variables like `name` or `in` .

I used this way `jsondata.map(sale => sale.child)` but it maps all child values. How can i do it?

Comment: Will be very useful to see the expected output of that data, or what you expect to get...

Comment: Hello thanks. when i select data ```"name": "abcd"``` my expected data would be ```        "child": [{
                    "name": "Test",
                    "in": 2,
                    "out": 2,
                    "net": 0,
                    "child": null
                },
                {
                    "name": "Max",
                    "in": 10,
                    "out": 0,
                    "net": 10,
                    "child": null
                }
            ] ```

Comment: It is still unclear for me, you want to map every **outter object** of the `item` array to the `child` array, but only when the sum of `in` variables of the childs is equal to the parent `in` value?

Answer (score 2):

you can use Filter to filter by name and hen map it like this.

```
let child = item
  .filter(sale => sale.name === "abcd" || sale.in === "value")
  .map(sale => sale.child);

console.log(child);
```

Answer (score 1):

You first need to filter and the use the map. For example if you are looking for the child of records which contain string "abc", you will do it like this

```
const records = items.filter(item => item.name.indexOf("abc") > -1);
const children = records.map(r => r.child)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can first `filter` item and then use `map`. If you want multiple conditions:

```
item.filter(sale => sale.name === "abcd" || sale.in === "value")
    .map(sale => console.log(sale.child));
```

Comment: It worked, thanks. Though i needed the dynamic value and i did that

Comment: @ManzurulHoqueRumi you can make if more simple by replacing **if(sale.name == "abcd" || sale.in == "value") return true;** with **sale => sale.name === "abcd" || sale.in === "value"**